# Given these static points, which is Bezier Curve

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have this question that is to determine the bezier curve that goes through theses points: (1,1), (2,-1), (3,1). How can we find the curve? I dont get how to use the equation. And how could we find the curves degree?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

There is infinity of Bezier curves through these points. You need to be more specific.

For example, one may define that curve is quadratic, the first point is starting one (t=0), the third is ending one (t=1) and the second is exact middle (t=0.5).
Then build equations (substituting t value and points coordinates) and solve them for coefficients

```
p[0].x * (1-t)^2 + p[1].x * 2 * t * (1-t) + p[2].x * t^2 = X(t)
example for the first point:
p[0].x * (1-0)^2 + p[1].x * 2 * 0 * (1-0) + p[2].x * (0)^2 = 1
p[0].x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A Bezier curve of degree N is a weighted sum of N+1 control points in 2D

```
Sum(i=0,N) Wi(t).Ci
```

If you have N+1 points Pj for which the values of t are known, you get a linear system of 2(N+1) equations in 2(N+1) unknowns

```
Sum(I=0,N) Wi(tj).Ci = Pj
```

The tj can be chosen uniformly in [0,1]. Another choice is using the cumulated linear distances between the control points (also reduced to [0,1]).

---

It is a very different matter if you don't want to provide the tj yourself. Then you can reduce the degree of the curve and trade control points for the values of t. Generally, the number of equations and unknowns cannot match and the system will be over or underdetermined.

Another difficulty is if you impose the order of the points. Then the unknowns t are constrained to be increasing, leading to a difficult system of equations and inequations.